# Visual studio 2010 - difference between Settings.settings and Resources.resx

Tags: visual-studio-2010

simple question here. What is the difference between putting a string in Settings.settings and putting a string in Resources.resx ?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

In Settings.setting the string will be placed in a config file, bassicaly a xml document which stores all kind of **information** your application needs to run. It's best practice to store configurable information in here. Also you can set the scope of the config value (**application and user**).
Application scoped config values will be shared among all users, while the user ones are limited to the current executing user of the application.

The .resx  file is the place for storing all kinds of **stuff** your application needs to run, like images and so on. Files in here should be normally not editable by the user, its as the name states, a resource pool for your application. Also resources are also always global.